# A way to test if https://www.google.com/jsapi available within intranet

Tags: google-visualization, intranet, web-access

I am working on an intranet application that uses the Google Visualization API to produce charts.

My question is is there a way to determine if access to https://www.google.com/jsapi server is down or blocked due to the company use of iPrism and display that information simply to the user on the page.

I know iPrism dosn't block it on my machine but i'm not sure about the client machines or that it may change in the future.

Any help is aapreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything you can trigger of of a script tag failing to load, but you could try to catch the failure before calling `google.load`, maybe with something like this?

```
if (typeof(google) == 'object' && typeof(google.load) == 'function') {
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
}
else {
    // display error message about failing to load jsapi
}
```

Comment: This does work, i originally tried to dynamically create a script so i could tie an event handler to it but that only caused more problems with google.load clearing the screen. Thanks for the help